# Can I track origin/master in a branch featureA and push the changes to the origin/featureA

Tags: git, merge, branch

I am just trying to work on a new featureA but would like to keep up with any commits coming from origin/master. Will the following work? is it the best way to do it?

```
git clone ssh://xxx/repo

git branch --track featureA origin/master

[do work on featureA and commit]

git commit -m"all changes made in featureA"

git push
```

day to day work:

```
git pull  (pull the latest from origin/master)

[merge the new commits coming from origin/master with my local featureA changes]

git commit -m"resolved conflicts"

git push origin/featureA
```

When time is ready to merge featureA into master:

```
git checkout master

git merge featureA

git push origin/master
```

does it sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout -b featureA origin/master #create the branch
git push origin featureA #push it up and track it
```

Update the master independently. You don't even need to check it out if you didn't commit anything on it (including merges of your feature):

```
git fetch
git push . origin/master:master
```

Now if you want to include those latest changes, you can

```
git merge master
```

When you want to include your changes in the master

```
git checkout master
git merge featureA
git push origin master #to send that up
```

I would not use pull as I usually like to see what was fetched with `git fetch` and then act accordingly with a merge or rebase or whatever.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. what does `git push . origin/master:master` do in the above.

Comment: It's a trick. The first argument is usually the remote name. If you provide the period instead it specifies the remote to be the same repo you're in. So I'm pushing what the tracking branch origin/master points to into the local master branch. :)

Comment: This is better than update-ref because it checks for fast forward and if it's not the case it will require the force option.